# Read mails from Folderin POP3 Server using ASP.Net C#

Tags: asp.net

I have created a shared mailbox in pop3 mail server.I am trying to read the mails from mailbox folder(like subfolders either inside inbox/outside).I am able to read and download the attachments from Inbox directly.But how can i read from Folder?

Please help me to come out of this issue

Comment: Which Folder ?What is there Inside the Folder ?

Comment: @Manish: Inside Inbox i have Created a folder to store a set of mails.These set of mails i will move always Inbox to the Folder(Created a Rule for this in Outlook).Created Rule to get mails from a particular Sender and moving these mails to Folder which Inside Inbox-->Folder

Comment: POP3 protocol support accessing inbox only. To access mail in other folders, you'll need a more advanced protocol like IMAP. Do the mail component and mail server you're using support IMAP?

Comment: @Alex:This is helpful.Mailbox which am using configured with POP3 ,thats why am trying to find possible ways within this.Which is better in performance POp3/IMAP?

Comment: @Veenet IMAP usually provides better performance (it's more flexible and you can request only the data you need). Anyway, you cannot access non-inbox folders with POP3 so there is no other choice but IMAP.

Comment: @Alex:Ok..Is there any way to access unique ID for each mail from pop3?Using POP3:- How can i skip the read mails at the second time?How to get unread mail  while running each time?Is it possible?

Comment: @Veenet You need to save all UIDs for all messages in your own db. On each sync, you compare UID list on the server with UID list in your db. The difference between these lists denotes what's new and what's no longer on the server. After downloading new emails from the server (and deleting local emails which are no longer on the server), you replace local UID list with the list of UIDs received from the server during the current session. In other words, local UID list is always a snapshot of the UID list from the server on the previous sync.

Comment: @Veenet on The first sync (when your local UID snapshot is empty), it just means that all emails are new. BTW, this approach works for IMAP just the same way.

Comment: @Alex:ok fine.Let me try this and see .Is there any documents to refer?or any sample code?

Comment: @Veenet I have code how to get UIDs from POP3 or IMAP server (but this depends on a particular mail library you're using). As for how to store them in db, this code needs to be written particularly for your db.

Comment: @Alex:ok fine. ' string uId = pop3Client.GetMessageUid(i);
               List<String> uIdArray = pop3Client.GetMessageUids();'But am getting diffrent UID on each execution.need to do any changes on mailbox settings?

Comment: @Veenet POP3 UIDs for the same messages should not change between sessions. I've never seen they change. You probably do something incorrectly. For instance, you may assume that `GetMessageUid(i)` should return the same value on each session but it's not so. If some old email was deleted, all `i` values beyond it will decrement. Message indices are not constant but UIDs are. You should not rely on `i`, only on UIDs.

Comment: @Alex:ok.I am using the method to get the message as per i value,like:' OpenPop.Mime.Message message = pop3Client.GetMessage(i);'.Is there any way to return message as per UID.I need to select all mail details as per UID.

Comment: Now am binding the unread mails to list and trying to fetch the unread mails using GetMessage(i),but still its returning the read mails.Any idea on this?

Comment: I don't understand why you keep using `GetMessage(i)` when only UIDs should be used. Forget message indices (`i`). They change from session to session.

Comment: @Alex:Thanks for your suggestion and support.i got exactly what i need...